# `bun build` replace references to env vars with actual values when bundling

Tags: javascript, bundle, bun

is there a way to make the `bun build` replace the references to env vars with their actual primitive value:

```js
console.log(Bun.env.API_KEY) // this get printed

// make a global variable for the API key
const API_KEY = Bun.env.API_KEY

const result = await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: ['./src/background.js', './src/content.js'], // specify the entrypoints of your extension
  outdir: './dist', // specify the output directory for the bundled files
  target: 'browser', // specify the target environment for the bundle
  format: 'esm', // specify the module format for the bundle
  external: ['chrome'], // specify any external imports that should not be bundled
})

if (!result.success) {
  console.error('Build failed')
  for (const message of result.logs) {
    // Bun will pretty print the message object
    console.error(message)
  }
}
```

the output in **dist** looks like:

> dist/content.js

```js
// src/content.js
var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
if (selectedText) {
  const url = `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(selectedText)}&key=${Bun.env.API_KEY}`; // Want the string instead of the ref
  ...
```

Comment: At the moment, only the macros functionality comes to mind: https://bun.sh/docs/bundler/macros , https://bun.sh/blog/bun-macros

Comment: I also thought of that, but can't figure out how to do it correctly with it.

Comment: I found the blog post link much more understandable than the docs.

Answer (score 1):

There definitely is. I just found it out. You use the Bun.env variables the way you normally would in your code, and then add this to the build object:

```
await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: [entrypoint],
  outdir: "./public",
  target: "browser",
  define: {
    "Bun.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID": JSON.stringify(Bun.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID),
    "Bun.env.DISCORD_API_ENDPOINT": JSON.stringify(Bun.env.DISCORD_API_ENDPOINT),
    "Bun.env.WEBSITE_BASE_URL": JSON.stringify(Bun.env.WEBSITE_BASE_URL),
  },
});
```

Source: https://bun.sh/docs/bundler#define

Confirmation from Bun Core Team Dev:
[image: Confirmation from Core Team Dev]

Answer (score 0):

this works but would like to find a more clean way of doing it.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

const result = await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: ['./src/background.js', './src/content.js', 'manifest.json', 'images/icon16.png'],
  outdir: './dist',
  target: 'browser',
  format: 'esm',
  external: ['chrome'], // specify any external imports that should not be bundled
})

if (result.success) {
  console.log('Build succeeded')
  exec(`sed -i '' 's/Bun.env.API_KEY/"${Bun.env.API_KEY}"/g' ./dist/src/content.js`)
}

if (!result.success) {
  console.error('Build failed')
  for (const message of result.logs) {
    // Bun will pretty print the message object
    console.error(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like I can also use https://bun.sh/guides/process/spawn - but I'm more looking for a way to bundle my PUBLIC env vars into the `/dist`